# Why Does Additional Data Fail To Be Sent To Server Method From jqGrid Using editData

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to send additional data to a method on the server using jqGrid editData property but it is not working. Basically when I select my jqGrid rows and then click the delete button which is the trash can icon, I would like to send some data to a method on the server.

Accord to my online search, additional data can be sent to server methods by simply adding them to the editData property in the code block for Edit of navGrid. Below is my a snippet of the navGrid code.

```
    .navGrid('#jqControls', { add: false, edit: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },

    //setting for add
    {},
    //Setting for edit
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        // sending extra parameter on click of submit after edit.
        // these values will be in signature of EditProductsDetails method in formcontroller as status and gridRowData. 
        editData: {
            status: "Active",
            gridRowData:function() {
                var cLIds = "[{";
                var i, selRowIds = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"), n, rowData;

                for (i = 0, n = selRowIds.length; i < n; i++) {
                    rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", selRowIds[i]);
                    if (i < n - 1) {
                        prdlIds += "{'ProductlineId': " + rowData.ProductlineId + "}, ";
                    } else {
                        prdlIds += "{'ProductlineId': " + rowData.ProductlineId + "}]";
                    }
                }
                var productlineIds = JSON.stringyfy(prdlIds);
                return productlineIds;
            }
        }           
    },       

    //setting for delete
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterDelete: true,
        recreateForm: true
    }, 
    //search setting
    { multipleSearch: true },
    { closeOnEscape: true }

    );
```

The following is the server method signature:

```
    EditProductsDetails(string oper, Products prod, string status, string gridRowData)
```

Comment: Which jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free jqGrid or jqGrid <=4.7? Why you perform on-line search instead of going into the documentation? For trash icon (deleting a row ) you will need to use delData in deloptions and not editData in edit options. If you use  Guriddo jqGrid you can see [these docs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#del-grid-row)

Comment: I'm using Guriddo jqGrid and I'm really new to it. I'm working on an existing code that someone else had written. I'm still trying to figure out for example how data are passed to the backend when the trash icon is clicked and neither data or post data were used to clearly state which pieces of data from the grid are sent back to editurl.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this code in delData instead in edit data. No need to serialize the json data, since you already have the string:

```
.navGrid('#jqControls', { add: false, edit: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },

//setting for add
{},
//Setting for edit
{
    zIndex: 100,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    recreateForm: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
},       

//setting for delete
{
    zIndex: 100,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterDelete: true,
    recreateForm: true,
    // sending extra parameter on click of submit after edit.
    // these values will be in signature of EditProductsDetails method in formcontroller as status and gridRowData. 
    delData: {
        status: "Active",
        gridRowData:function() {
            var prdlIds = "[{";
            var i, selRowIds = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"), n, rowData;

            for (i = 0, n = selRowIds.length; i < n; i++) {
                rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", selRowIds[i]);
                if (i < n - 1) {
                    prdlIds += "{'ProductlineId': " + rowData.ProductlineId + "}, ";
                } else {
                    prdlIds += "{'ProductlineId': " + rowData.ProductlineId + "}]";
                }
            }
            // no need to serialize prdlIds is already a string
            return prdlIds;
        }
    }           

}, 
//search setting
{ multipleSearch: true },
{ closeOnEscape: true }

);
```